# SignalR on IIS dropping connections

Tags: c#, wpf, iis, signalr

I have a production chat application that uses SignalR. Phase one is all in memory mapping of connections. I use a static dictionary with GUIDs for the roomname/groupname. I map the connections in my dictionary to mimic the same add/remove calls I make in Groups, so that I can use Clients.Group(roomname) or Clients.Group(Connection.RoomName) to send messages to a subset of people.

However seemingly randomly, maybe once or twice a week all of my desktop users are disconnected, they can immediately reconnect by re-launching the application. It seems they reconnect when they are dropped, but not entirely as they will receive calls even though they aren't supposed to because they are "away" and the calls will be empty, meaning they have the information necessary to manipulate the group but they aren't a part of the group.

Could this be an issue with Reconnecting/Reconnected firing but not rejoining all the appropriate groups(since that isn't guaranteed)? I handle onconnected, and ondisconnected but I do nothing with onReconnected.

It could also be a memory issue on the server, but I don't think I am exceeding the maximum memory allowed, since all I store is text, and objects with text. And I clear the connections once they conversation is over.

Some relevant code(out of context, obviously):

```
     public class Connection
       {
          private string roomName;
          private Dictionary<string, ChatUser> users;
          private List<ChatMessage> messages;
          private bool answered;
          private CRMHub crmHub;
          private DateTime createdOn;


  public static Dictionary<string, Connection> Connections = new Dictionary<string, Connection>();


 conn = new Connection(personalRoom);
           conn.Users.Add(Context.User.Identity.Name, tempUser);
           Connections.Add(personalRoom, conn);
           Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, personalRoom);
```